# How do I see what docker-compose build is doing?

Tags: docker-compose

docker-compose build is failing.   I want to see what docker-compose build is doing so I can reproduce it step by step and drill down into the problem.  What I'm interested in is a process for finding out what's wrong, not a solution to my current problem.   Setting --log-level DEBUG doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: Consider using `--verbose` for more output. Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

Comment: @Vadym thanks.. that does provide more info.   But not the info I need?   It's doing something akin to docker builds under the hood isn't it?   Can I see what it's trying to do somehow?

I can't see the steps it's trying to take? (maybe I can and I don't understand what I'm looking at).